# Crash on [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibnamed:owner:options:]

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, nib

I cannot figure this one out. I have a created a custom UITableViewCell in IB. As far as I can tell I have all the objects in the cell which are all UILabels wired up properly and everything builds without any errors. When I try to use the custom cell the app stops when I try to load the NIB. I've listed what I have in place for this below.

Any help or hints or where to look to figure this one out would be appreciated.

Thanks,

John

Here are my UITableViewCell interface and implementation methods. I am not sure I really needed to alloc init the labels. I tried it both ways...

```
//  ArrivalTimesCell.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ArrivalTimesCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UILabel *cityArrivalTimeLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *optimumArrivalTimeLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *arrivalAvoidTimesLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *arrivalTimeNotSetLabel;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *cityArrivalTimeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *optimumArrivalTimeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *arrivalAvoidTimesLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *arrivalTimeNotSetLabel;

@end

//  ArrivalTimesCell.m

#import "ArrivalTimesCell.h"

@implementation ArrivalTimesCell
@synthesize arrivalTimeNotSetLabel, arrivalAvoidTimesLabel, optimumArrivalTimeLabel, cityArrivalTimeLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        arrivalTimeNotSetLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        arrivalAvoidTimesLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        optimumArrivalTimeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        cityArrivalTimeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

}

- (void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [arrivalTimeNotSetLabel release];
    arrivalTimeNotSetLabel = nil;
    [arrivalAvoidTimesLabel release];
    arrivalAvoidTimesLabel = nil;
    [optimumArrivalTimeLabel release];
    optimumArrivalTimeLabel = nil;
    [cityArrivalTimeLabel release];
    cityArrivalTimeLabel = nil;
}

@end
```

Here is a portion of cellForRowAtIndexPath for the UITableView

```
//  TripEditViewController.m

#import "ArrivalTimesCell.h"

@implementation TripEditViewController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CellIdentifier = @"ArrivalTimesCell";
    ArrivalTimesCell *cell = (ArrivalTimesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ArrivalTimesCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (ArrivalTimesCell *) currentObject;
                break;
             }
         }      
    }


    cell.cityArrivalTimeLabel.text = @"Whatever"
    cell.arrivalAvoidTimesLabel.text = @"Whatever";
    cell.optimumArrivalTimeLabel.text = @"Whatever";
    cell.arrivalTimeNotSetLabel.text = @"Whatever";

    return cell;  
}
```

Program execution stops on the loadNibNamed line without any comment in the console. If I "step into" I get the following which I am not sure has anything to do with the cause of my crash but instead is the result of the nib not loading properly...

> 2011-03-29 12:18:14.137 JetLogger[4565:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key cityArrivalTimeLabel.'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0111a5a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0126e313 objc_exception_throw + 44
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0111a4e1 -[NSException raise] + 17
>       3   Foundation                          0x000ca677 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
>       4   Foundation                          0x000ca5e5 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
>       5   UIKit                               0x0054e30c -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
>       6   CoreFoundation                      0x010908cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
>       7   UIKit                               0x0054cd23 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
>       8   UIKit                               0x0054eab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
>       9   JetLogger                           0x0004bf18 -[TripEditViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 699
>       10  UIKit                               0x003c7b98 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 634
>       11  UIKit                               0x003bd4cc -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 75
>       12  UIKit                               0x003d28cc -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1561
>       13  UIKit                               0x003ca90c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 242
>       14  QuartzCore                          0x02051a5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
>       15  QuartzCore                          0x02053ddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
>       16  QuartzCore                          0x01ff90b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
>       17  QuartzCore                          0x01ffa294 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
>       18  QuartzCore                          0x01ffa46d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
>       19  CoreFoundation                      0x010fb89b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 27
>       20  CoreFoundation                      0x010906e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
>       21  CoreFoundation                      0x010591d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
>       22  CoreFoundation                      0x01058840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>       23  CoreFoundation                      0x01058761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
>       24  GraphicsServices                    0x01a081c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
>       25  GraphicsServices                    0x01a08289 GSEventRun + 115
>       26  UIKit                               0x00360c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
>       27  JetLogger                           0x00001ba8 main + 102
>       28  JetLogger                           0x00001b39 start + 53
>   )
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Somewhere in your nib, you connect something to the cityArrivalTimeLabel property on an object that does not have that property. Make sure you 1) changed the class of the cell to ArrivalTimesCell and 2) connected that label to the right object.

You do not need to alloc/init the labels in your init method. They are simply replaced when the nib loads, so it is just a waste of RAM until then.

Comment: OK, thanks. I rechecked and in the NIB both File's Owner and the UITableViewCell has their Class popup selected to ArrivalTimesCell. I have also double checked that the four UILabels are in act UILabels and are connected to the prober properties in ArrivalTimesCell.h (file's Owner). I am going to recreate the xib from scratch. Perhaps that will help.

Comment: Still does not work. Do you think the NIB is loading at all? I put a break in the initWithStyle method of ArrivalsTimeCell.m and it never breaks.

Comment: The problem is that you connected the labels to the File's Owner, but when you call loadNibNamed..., you pass nil as the file's owner. You should connect the labels to the cell object in the nib. initWithStyle: will not be called when loading from a nib. Nib loading uses initWithCoder: to initialize the object and calls awakeFromNib after the nib is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed was the problem. I had tried connecting both ways but when I had it connected correctly with the cell I got an error which I did not read assuming it was the same error, which it was not. The new error occurs when I return the cell and is..  "UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:". The cell looks to be initialized with the 4 labels properly set just before I return it. If you have any hints as to what I should do to fix the new problem that would be great.

Comment: Got it. There are actually 2 tables being handled by the view controller with an if statement in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and I was returning the cell with a single call outside of the if statement. I changed this to return the cell for each table inside the if statement and it is now working great. Thanks for your help!